# Where to start for Jruby on rails?

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails

Any tutorials or blog are available to start with JRuby on Rails
which guide me to the installation and small JRuby on Rails application ?
I have gone through this  Walkthroughs And Tutorials(https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/WalkthroughsAndTutorials) link but most of the JRuby on Rails links are broken.

Answer (score 10):

**JRuby and Rails Installation**

The easiest way to set up JRuby is using rvm.  The following command installs rvm, the latest version if JRuby, and gets the latest version of rails:

```sh
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=3 --ruby=jruby --gems=rails
```

On Windows, you can [download](http://www.jruby.org/download) an installer which will set up JRuby for you.  You then need to install rails by running the following command:

```sh
jruby -S gem install rails
```

**Set up a Rails project**

JRuby’s wiki page [JRuby on Rails](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JRubyOnRails) is a great collection of resources on the topic; it contains in particular a link to that good blog post: http://blog.rubyrockers.com/2011/03/rails3-application-jruby/

In a nutshell, to create a rails project based on JRuby, use the following command, replacing `my_app` with the name of your project:

```sh
rails new my_app -m https://www.jruby.org/templates/default.rb
```

**Rails Development**

Once your project is set up, any [Rails 3 tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) will do — it is Ruby after all!

**Deployment**

For deployment, have a look at:

- “specific” solutions like [Torquebox](http://torquebox.org/) or [Trinidad](http://thinkincode.net/trinidad/),
- or [warbler](http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/warbler/) to package your app as a war and deploy in traditional Java app server (WebSphere, Weblogic, etc.).

**Further Resources**

Finally, it is also worth mentioning that Charles Nutter et al's book [Using JRuby](http://pragprog.com/book/jruby/using-jruby) has a chapter dedicated to JRuby on Rails, and is an invaluable help in JRuby developments.

Comment: Do you have idea how to develop rails+jruby application in eclipse(With debug enabled)?