# jruby: No such file or directory -- rails (LoadError)

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails

I was trying to create a jruby application using `jruby -S rails new OSTH_GGG`.

But it returns `jruby: No such file or directory -- rails (LoadError)`.

What is the problem?

Comment: What version of JRuby?  What about plain `rails new appname` ? Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the `rails` gem is installed:

```
jruby -S gem install rails
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884952/where-to-start-for-jruby-on-rails/9885284#9885284) to get more details on how to get started with JRuby on Rails.